# Gmail pop out message composer with shortcut

Tags: gmail

Sometimes while writing an email in gmail I need to "pop out" the composer window to back to my inbox and check something. Is there a shortcut to do this?

I know about shift + c for opening a new message composer in a separate window, but often I'm already writing a message when I need this function. Also, yes there's is the little top right button you can click with the mouse, but I'd love to be able to do this via a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

I like tinkering with Gmail, so I made a [small script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105789) to do what you asked. It works for me in Firefox 5.0 with Greasemonkey.

The shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+Z. You can go through the source and change the shortcut if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd>d</kbd> - it's a Gmail shortcut to open compose in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

The latest short cut for opening a new compose window in Gmail:

> Try holding down the shift key while clicking compose - it opens a
>   brand new compose window in the center of your screen, perfect for
>   those who like a little extra space!

See the following Google+ **[post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/103345707817934461425/posts/PK7qe79qeYC)** from Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

From the inline compose form, type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move focus to the menu, use the arrow keys to navigate to "Pop out reply", then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

For Compose pop-out simply press key "C"

To open Compose completely in new window "**Shift+c**"

**Shift+a** (Reply All) **Shift+r** (Reply) and **Shift+f** (Forward)

*Note: These shortcuts will work if you have turned "**Keyboard Shortcuts**" ON under Gmail settings.*

Comment: Those just open the regular compose window. The Asker is asking for a command to use the "pop-out" compose window.